# Using Powershell, how are dropdown based custom webpart properties set?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I have the following Powershell function:

```
function Add-WebPartToPage {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param( 
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
   [System.Object]$web, 

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] 
   [string]$pageTitle,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] 
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$list,       

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
   [System.Object]$webpart,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]       
   [string]$webPartTitle,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=5)]       
   [string]$panelTitle,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=6)]       
   [int]$CSPUElevel,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=7)]       
   [int]$panelType 
) 
   Process 
{ 
    #if webpart specified then add it to the page
    if($webpart)
    {
        $pageName = $list.Title + "/$pageTitle.aspx"
        $pageName = $pageName -replace " ",""
        $page = $web.GetFile($pageName)
        $page.CheckOut()
        $mgr = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageName, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

        if($webPartTitle)
        {
            $webpart.Title = $webPartTitle
        }
        $webpart.ChromeType = "None"
        #++ Extended Settings
        if($webpart.GetType().Name -eq "DynamicWebPart")
        {
        # 
            $pinProperties = $webpart.GetType().GetProperties()
            foreach ($prop in $pinProperties)
            {
                if(($panelTitle) -and ($prop.Name -eq "PanelTitle"))
                {   
                    $webpart.PanelTitle = $panelTitle
                }
                if(($CSPUElevel) -and ($prop.Name -eq "CSPUElevel"))
                {
                    $webpart.CSPUElevel = $CSPUElevel
                }
                if(($panelType) -and ($prop.Name -eq "PanelType"))
                {
                    $webpart.PanelType = $panelType
                }
            }
        }
        #-- End of Extended Settings
        $mgr.AddWebPart($webpart, "FullPage", 0)
        Write-Host -f Green "Webpart $webpart.WebBrowsableObject added to the page"

        $page.CheckIn("Checked in Automatically")
        #$page.Publish("Published Automatically")
    }
 }

}
```

Everything works fine until it gets to the extended properties of the webpart. Within that logic, the panel title will set correctly. This is a direct string assignment to the custom property. However, the CSPUElevel and PanelType are dropdowns and the assignment is never made. What is more interesting is that the CSPUElevel and PanelType don't seem to be exposed as custom properties in the same way as the Panel Title. In other words, the test for $prop.Name is never equal to "CSPUElevel" or "PanelType".

From the webpart (DynamicWebPart.cs):

```
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        DynamicWebPartUserControl control = (DynamicWebPartUserControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        control.Panel = (DynamicWebPartUserControl.PanelOption)this.Panel;
        control.PanelTitle = this.PanelTitle;
        control.CSPUEBreadCrumbSelected = (DynamicWebPartUserControl.Breadcrumb)this.BreadcrumbSelected;
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
```

From the webpart (DynamicWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs):

```
    public enum PanelOption
    {
        None = 0,
        AdministrativeInfo = 1,
        GeneralInfo = 2,
        Engineering = 3
    }

    public PanelOption Panel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Panel type definition:

```
        private DynamicWebPartUserControl.PanelOption _Panel = 0;

    [Category("SPS - Extended Settings"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Panel Type"),
    WebDescription("Please select the type of panel to display")]
    public DynamicWebPartUserControl.PanelOption Panel
    {
        get { return this._Panel; }
        set { this._Panel = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Why using reflection, instead of directly specifing webpart type ?

Comment: This function is part of a larger installation script.  Its intent is to generically support the addition of a webpart to the page.  For example some times it is called to add a navigation webpart to the page, sometimes it is used to add specific editor webparts, and in the case where I'm having issues its being called to add a dynamic web part to the page.  The exposed properties set through the dynamic webpart are parameters used to query a db table that controls which fields are displayed on the screen.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How is dynamic WebPart implemented? How do you expect to have properties (meaning .net properties) exposed on the fly from a DB ?

Comment: That said, you may explore Xml Importation of your webpart. It's probably easier to build an XmlDocument using several `<property name='xy'>My Value</property>` then importing the webpart with this definition

Comment: Modified the question to hopefully add some clarity.  The CSPUE - company, site, plant, unit, equipment is set and the corresponding area of information; admin, engineering, general.  The db is queried to get the fields to collect; name, datatype, combo, text and then controls are dynamically added to the webpart server side at runtime.

Comment: I still believe you should declare your argument `$webpart` as your actual class DynamicWebPart and directly set the property. No need to reflect here. Moreover, powershell is dynamic... it will succeed to set the property even if you declare the parameter as object.

Comment: How are "CSPUElevel" or "PanelType" defined? Your code snippet does not mention it

Comment: And take a look at [http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2013-04-16-powershell-simplifier-la-creation-de-fonction-avec-les-bons-arguments.htm#more-332](http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2013-04-16-powershell-simplifier-la-creation-de-fonction-avec-les-bons-arguments.htm#more-332). It's in french, but you may found useful how to declare Web parameter